# Stackblitz not reaching component's scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components, stackblitz

I'm trying to use [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) with AngularJS, however the purposed old sintax of routing `controller` and `view` is kind of obsolete, so I'm modifying the base example to use `ui-router` and [AngularJS 1.5 Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

```
<h1>Hello {{$ctrl.name}}!</h1>
```

The problem I'm having is that seems that [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) is not attaching properly the `$ctrl` or `$scope` into the component's template, but it's injecting the template properly.

(I tried to add the component's tag and bindings and pass values `<home name="AngularJS">` and seems to work but the problem I have is with the routing)

[Here is the example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-sbkpqs?file=home%2Fhome.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the `home.js` and it works. Check it please. Is it what you need?

```
import template from './home.html';
import ctrl from './home.controller.js';

let module = angular.module('home', [])
  .component('home', {

    // this line
    controller: ctrl,

    template
  })
  .name;

  export default module;
```

Comment: Thank you, I misspelled the component declaration, I applied the fix and works as intended!